# Trigger Woocommerce New User Email

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, email, user-registration

I wrote a custom plugin that handles login and registration for my WordPress Woocommerce site.

When a user registers via my custom form handler I would like to trigger Woocommerce to send the new user an email instead of using wp_mail. This way I reduce code redundancy, and all of the transactional emails can be formatted the same (they all have the same look and feel).

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Anyone looking for an answer of this can visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226823/woo-commerce-new-user-email